# Drawer items not taking whole width

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a menu drawer with several items, and for some reason the items don't take the whole width of the drawer, even though layout_width is match parent.
Here's the drawer_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_user_current"
        android:title=""
        app:actionLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_current_user_profile" />

</menu>
```

Here is nav_drawer_current_user_profile.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_chat_room_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_large"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_large"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_person_avatar_blue_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_user_profile_nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Current user"
        android:textColor="@color/light_blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/nav_drawer_font_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The drawer itself is in this file base_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu_chat"/>
```

And this is how the menu is rendered

[image]

How can I make the item to be in the right, and to take all the width of the drawer?

Comment: @Thunder but I did

Comment: @Thunder edited it

Answer (score 2):

try

```
android:title="@null"
```

in menu item

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-65dp"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu_chat"/>
```